# Avoiding submodules while looping through all list of submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

We have a considerable quantity of submodules and we would like to go through all of them using `git submodule foreach git <command>`.

What happens is that 1 or 2 of these submodules do not need these command to be used on them, so I was wondering if there could be a way to avoid looping these submodules previously specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... I was wondering if there could be a way to avoid looping these submodules previously specified.

No, there is not.  But `git submodule foreach` runs *an arbitrary shell command*, with some variables exported, as [described in the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html):

> foreach [--recursive] <command>
>
> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule.
>    The command has access to the variables `$name`, `$sm_path`,
>    `$displaypath`, `$sha1` and `$toplevel`: `$name` is the name of the
>    relevant submodule section in `.gitmodules`, `$sm_path` is the path of
>    the submodule as recorded in the immediate superproject,
>    `$displaypath` contains the relative path from the current working
>    directory to the submodules root directory, `$sha1` is the commit as
>    recorded in the immediate superproject, and `$toplevel` is the
>    absolute path to the top-level of the immediate superproject. Note
>    that to avoid conflicts with `$PATH` on Windows, the `$path` variable
>    is now a deprecated synonym of `$sm_path` variable. ...

(I made some minor formatting-directive changes here but the text should match up, more or less.  Your Git version may have the older `$path` name rather than `$sm_path`, depending on the age of your Git.  Check *your* Git's documentation to be sure: `git help submodule` will print out the above, as part of the full documentation.)

Since you have access to all of this information, *use it*.  Pick whichever is simplest to check for the situation you have and skip executing commands that do not apply.  Don't just blindly run `git foo`; use `if somecondition; then git foo; fi` or similar.

Comment: Hi @torek, thank you for your answer. How can I manage to add conditions to the git command? Is that some kind of script or similar? If possible, could you give me an example or redirect me to something similar?

Comment: "Shell" is a scripting language: see [tag:shell], https://stackoverflow.com/tags/shell/info